# Timer for getting input in TASM 8086

Tags: assembly, input, timer, x86-16, tasm

I need to make a played in turns game for 2 players. Each player should have a timer for each turn that allows them to play (press a key) in the time provided (let's say for instance 20 seconds, it can be whatever). How can I make it so that the int116h(ah=1) lasts the time i want instead of forever?

I tried to make the program "sleep" the time i wanted after the call to the interrupt but, as it is after the interrupt, it never stops. After that I tried to make a loop for N times where at the end it sleeps 1 second, but still it is after the input interrupt, so it never loops.

Fragment of code i want to time:

```
GET_INPUT PROC FAR
    MOV AH, 1
    MOV SI, TURN
    INT 16H
    MOV INPUT[SI], AL
GET_INPUT ENDP
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. You should have no problem spinning in a loop and checking the time. Show your code.

Comment: This would be the code i want to add a timer to. If i wrap this into a loop, the loop gets stuck in the interruption as it is waiting for input (added to question)

Comment: int16/01 does not wait for input, it should not get stuck.

Comment: Oh then I'll check if I have any other errors around it, thanks!

Comment: If you are using DOS, you can use [int21h/ah=2ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2703.htm) to get the time. Once at the start of `GET_INPUT` and then in each iteration of a loop that would also call `int16h/ah=01h` and exit as soon as an input is present of the timeout elapsed. Without DOS, `int1ah/ah=00h` will return the ticks (18.2 per second) elapsed since midnight, or you can read them from the BDA (IIRC) or read the seconds from the CMOS or hook `int 1ch`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> GET_INPUT PROC FAR
>   MOV AH, 1
>   MOV SI, TURN
>   INT 16H
>   MOV INPUT[SI], AL
> GET_INPUT ENDP
> ```

- It will be best to keep `mov ah, 1` adjacent to `int 16h`. That `mov si, TURN` looks very much out of place.
- This BIOS function only *checks* for a keystroke. The keystroke remains in the keyboard buffer and that buffer will soon be filled.

For your timeout on the player's turn, you can use a couple of nested loops like I wrote in below code snippet.

```
GET_INPUT PROC FAR
 ;; push ...
 mov  bx, 364   ; Timeout of 20 seconds == 18.2 * 20 ticks
OuterLoop:
 mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetTickCount
 int  1Ah       ; -> CX:DX
 mov  si, dx    ; New reference tick
InnerLoop:
 mov  ah, 01h   ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
 int  16h       ; -> AX ZF
 jnz  GotKey
 mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetTickCount
 int  1Ah       ; -> CX:DX
 cmp  dx, si    ; Compare current tick with the reference tick
 je   InnerLoop ; While not changed, stay in the inner loop
 dec  bx
 jnz  OuterLoop ; Go get a new reference (*)
 xor  ax, ax    ; Returning 0 for 'no key pressed'
 jmp  Done
GotKey:
 mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetKeystroke (removes the key from the buffer)
 int  16h       ; -> AX
Done:
 mov  bx, TURN
 mov  INPUT[bx], ax
 ;; pop ...
GET_INPUT ENDP
```

- (*) Most of the time the new reference is just 1 more than the previous reference, however not so around midnight.
- This code now uses AX, BX, CX, DX, and SI. If necessary preserve the ones that should not get modified.
- I think that this code would be the correct place where you should  toggle the player. E.g. If *TURN* is either 0 or 2 (based on you storing AX), you could have:

```
 xor  TURN, 2
GET_INPUT ENDP
```